# Accessing static members of a class within static methods

Tags: java, static

I have this code in java I write it by netbeans

```
class sample
{
    public static int x;
    public int y;
    sample()
    {
        x=0;
    }
}
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    sample cchild=new sample();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        sample.x=0;
        cchild.x=9; // here error
    }
```

explain the sample :

I make composition to class **sample** , class **sample** contain static variable **x** , But when I try to access to static variable **x** from the instance **cchild** in static method the compiler make error,
so in java I can not access to object in static methode even the instance contain static member ???

Comment: ok , But I can access by cchild to static member , it allow me to access to static member by the name of class , why I can not access to static member by name of instance in static methode ?@Johnny Mopp

Comment: if the methode not static I can refer a static field through object @Abhishek

Comment: @kernal I think you are misunderstanding...the problem is not with accessing x through cchild...that's possible...the problem is accessing cchild (a non-static) inside a static function

Comment: @Abhishek Your statement : "Static field can be used through class only.". is not true.

Comment: ok now I get it , thanks @Rakesh G R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that `static` members belong to a `class` and not an instance and can therefore be accessed directly without the need to create a reference to an instance of the class. The following statement accesses the `static` member `x` in class `sample` where `sample` is the class name and `x` is the `static` member in `sample` :

> sample.x=0;

The following statement on the other hand does not work because 
the reference `cchild` is not `static` and is thus an instance field while `main` is a `static` method. An instance field cannot be accessed in a `static` method without a reference to an instance of the class.

> cchild.x=9

For the above statement to work, you either declare `cchild` as `static` in `JavaApplication1` or create an instance of `JavaApplication1` in `main` as shown below :

```
JavaApplication1 instanceOfJApp = new JavaApplication1();
instanceOfJApp.cchild.x=9;
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work. You need to declare the variable cchild to be a static member of the JavaApplicaiton1 class to be able to access it statically.

```
class sample
{
    public static int x;
    public int y;
    sample()
    {
        x=0;
    }
}

public class JavaApplication1 {

    // NEW BIT - by making this variable static we can now access it without needing an instance of the object.
    static sample cchild=new sample();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sample.x=0;
        cchild.x=9;
    }
}
```

Static in Java means it is a property of the class itself and not a property of an instance object of that class's type. When using non-static properties you need to have created an object of that class's type by calling a constructor and then you can use that object's reference to call non-static methods and access non-static variables. If you don't have a copy of an object of that type then you can only call the static methods and access the static variables.

The original didn't work because although you were trying to access the static variable from a static context (inside the main method which is static) you were creating the variable you used to access the static variable (cchild) in a non-static context (in the class definition). By not labelling the cchild variable 'static' it becomes an instance variable of the JavaApplication1 class and so can only be used if you create an instance of the JavaApplication1 class by calling a constructor, and not in the main method which is created statically.

I have suggested here that you change the variable to be static so that you can access it. I think this is the easiest way for you to make progress. However, in general, if you get stuck needing to make a change like this it probably shows that you need to think more about which members need to be static and which need to be on the instance object and so just making the variable static might not always be the best thing to do.

There are a few other things you might do differently in this code example. The first is that I would suggest that you use the Java naming convention of starting the name of your classes with a capital letter (Sample instead of sample in this case) otherwise they do not look like class names to Java people.

Comment: Please add at least a short explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are only helpful to those fully understanding the code - and that audience wouldn't look into this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things you can do to fix your problem:

1. Make `cchild` static
2. Move the declaration of `cchild` to your `main` method

Answer (score 1):

It's because invoking

```
static void main(String[] args){
}
```

doesn't make the JavaApplication1 instance.